# Proof of a series convergence

Tags: complex-analysis, convergence-divergence

Suppose $$g(z) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_nz^n$$ on $B_R(0)$. Then the series
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n(z-z_0)^{(-n)}$$ converges to a function f(z) for all $|z − z_0| > 1/R $, and convergence is uniform on the set ${z ∈ C : |z − z_0| ≥ r}$ for any r > 1/R.

I know I am supposed to use $f(z) = g(\frac{1}{z-z_0})$ but wasn't sure where to go after that.

Comment: Just substitute $t = (z-z_0)^{-1}$.

Comment: Where you go after that is applying that same substitution to $B_R(0)$ and a certain theorem about power series.